# Working methods to enable MSMQ programatically on Win7+

Tags: msmq

from my own experience on Windows 7 MSMQ can be enabled via console using:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:"MSMQ-Server" /all
```

How about any other alternative reliable methods that can be used for Windows7 and later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here https://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/WindowsFeatureViaCmd.html we have a list with available methods that can be used to enable Windows Features (not only MSMQ) depending on target operating system.

It helped me, I hope it will help you also.